# Vuetify Treeview

Tags: javascript, treeview, vuetify.js

I have created a Vuetify Treeview. I have made the component selectable. The idea is that you can select the entire tree and after clicking a button it will sum up everything in the treeview and spit out a quantity of each item required to make a recipe. However, some items like salt are used multiple times within the treeview. How can I make sure that even though the item has the same name it is counted twice?

Additionally, they seem connected on the treeview. If I select one the other is also selected, even if it is nested inside of another item.

Comment: you're probably *doing something wrong ™* in the code that creates the data for the treeview

Comment: Could you give me an example please?

Comment: as I can't see what you are doing, I can't see what you are doing wrong - how can I give you an example if I know nothing about your data or code?

Answer (score 1):

```
:item-key="id"
```

add this props on your tree
if you select a different element it uses id and does not select two elements